# Why is this not renaming my file?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am using file.copyfile to rename my file but it doesnt seem to be working the filename is staying the same ?

```
    Dim _filename As String
    Dim _path As String
    Dim _newfilename As String

    _filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename)
    _path = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename)
    _newfilename = _filename & "." & extension
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(filename,
    _newfilename, True)
```

Comment: Copying a file does not rename a file - it copies it. Please can you edit your question to clarify exactly what you are trying to do? You probably want to look at File.Move (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218910/rename-a-file-in-c-sharp)

Comment: according to the documentation it will rename the file indeed http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36xbexyf(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: The documentation does not say it will rename the original file. It can overwrite an existing file or copy to a new name (rename), but the original file wills tay the same unless you Move it as per the other comments

Comment: Sorry.. Misread RB's answer.

Comment: @SysDragon It might be a conceptual duplicate, but frankly that answer sucks.  Is that the best dupe out there?  If so, then a more complete answer here would serve the community better.

Comment: @DonBoitnott Or a better answer there. A duplicate question is independent of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(currentFileName, NewFileName)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w05844e.aspx

I think your code below is setting _newfilename to be the name of the file and is not including a directory. The file is being copied to the root folder where the application is running I think. RenameFile should work ok for what you need I think. Let me know if this is ok.

```
_newfilename = _filename & "." & extension
```