# C# changing the name of a JPEG image

Tags: c#, jpeg, renaming

I'm trying to go through and rename a bunch of my JPG but what I'm trying won't work and i have no idea what else to try.

**The program works for folders and .txt but not my .JPG images**, there are other solutions to renaming but not for .JPG. Does anyone know what I can change?

I have also tried `File.Move` but they both return the same error message,
`File not found exception was unhandled. Could not find file` (I am certain my path is correct)

```
private void startRenaming_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string old_name = @"C:\Users\u587945\Desktop\Vial_Suction_Test\Postion_1\Cycle_1.JPG",
           new_name = @"C:\Users\u587945\Desktop\Vial_Suction_Test\Postion_1\Cycle_1_Vial_1.JPG";

    bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(old_name);
    if (exists)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Found Directory!!!");
        System.IO.Directory.Move(old_name, new_name);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Directory not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use File.Exists and File.Move?

Comment: Why doesn't this work? What _does_ it do?

Comment: Marking as duplicate based on title. Your sample code uses `Directory` API, so the duplicate may actually be unrelated to want you want to do - feel free to edit title/post to make it clear what exact issue you having and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Use **System.IO.File.Move**, not **Directory**
Check [Rename a file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218910/rename-a-file-in-c-sharp)