# How to change excel filename

Tags: c#, excel

My question is how to we change the excel filename without we manual changing by our own?
Example , i get a list of naming from excel format from vendor and he will put on the specified location . I need to run a program which using this file to generate a cancellation progress with a specific format of excel in MMYYSP15.

Here my code and i wish to add on the function as i need . Kindly advise

```
object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass xl = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlBook;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlSheet;
//System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oldCI;

string laPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("D:\\New & Renewal Summary Report 201409.xls");
xlBook = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook)xl.Workbooks.Open(laPath, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);

xlSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
xlSheet.Name = "Sheet 1";
xlBook.Save();
xl.Application.Workbooks.Close();
```

Comment: If you want to change the name of the file, then use ```File.Move()``` More details there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218910/rename-a-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: Hi Gregoire , so i just implement this method on the code ?System.IO.File.Move("oldfilename", "newfilename");

Comment: Yes like @Patrick Hofman suggested below, where ```fromFileName``` would be ```laPath``` in your code, and ```toFileName``` would be the path with the new name you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call [`xlBook.SaveAs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas.aspx). You can't change the current file's name.

```
xlBook.SaveAs(Filename: yourFileName);
```

If you do not intend to do anything with the Excel workbook itself, a simple [`File.Move`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would do.

```
File.Move(fromFileName, toFileName);
```