# If File Already Exists Rename it

Tags: c#, file-exists, file-copying

I am wanting to use `File.Copy` to copy a file to a directory.  That is straightforward.  Does `File.Copy` have an overload that can rename if the file already exists, or do I need to bundle `File.Copy` with `File.Exist`

Comment: Have you consulted MSDN?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218910/rename-a-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Minh - I saw it had an overwrite parameter I didn't see it had a rename one.

Comment: how could it rename it? two files are defined to be the "same" if they have the same name, how would it know what file to rename to what?

Comment: @DLeh - I am needing to copy a few files from test over to production (which may or may not exist).  If the file already exist, I was going to rename by appending the date to the end of the filename.  Does that help clarify my initial question?

Comment: You could have easily discovered this on your own with a little research on the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: It's not such a strange question, Windows Explorer does just this. But I think Explorer has its own logic for that, it's not an OS function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with `File.Move` to rename a file:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

and yes - you'll still want to check its existence with `File.Exists`

Answer (score 1):

There is no such overload, so you have to use `File.Exists` and `File.Copy`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i am aware File.copy does not have an overload that allows renaming.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.file.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
There is one to allow over writing and one to make a plain copy.