# C# File and Renaming Automatically from 1?

Tags: c#, .net, file, directory

I wrote this code in c# for change location of folder and all sub-folders of this folder. I want to change name of all folders when copy it to destination.  for example I want to change name from 1 to .... . how should I change my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Folder
{
    class clssMoveFolder
    {

        string temppath;
        public string StrtxtSource;
        public string destDirName;

        public void Directorycopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool cutSubDirs, string strExtension)
        {
           try
            {

                DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);
                DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
                // If the source directory does not exist, throw an exception.

                if (!dir.Exists)
                {
                    throw new DirectoryNotFoundException("Source directory does not exist or could not be found: " + sourceDirName);
                }
                FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
                if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
                }
                //Get the file contents of the directory to copy.
                for (int a = 0; a < files.Length; ++a)
                {
                    // Create the path to the new copy of the file.
                    if (files[a].Extension == "."+strExtension  )
                    {
                        temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, files[a].Name);
                        files[a].MoveTo(temppath);
                    }
                    else if (files[a].Extension == strExtension)
                    {
                        temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, files[a].Name);
                        files[a].MoveTo(temppath);
                    }
                    else if (strExtension == "AllFiles")
                    {
                        temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, files[a].Name);
                        files[a].MoveTo(temppath);
                    }
                    else
                        files[a].Delete();
                   dir.Refresh();
                }
                FileInfo[] filesCheck = dir.GetFiles();
                if (dirs.Length == 0 && filesCheck.Length == 0 && dir.Name != StrtxtSource)
                {
                    dir.Delete();
                }

                // If copySubDirs is true, copy the subdirectories.
                if (cutSubDirs)
                {

                    foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
                    {

                        // Copy the subdirectories.

                        string temppath= Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);

                        Directorycopy(subdir.FullName, temppath,cutSubDirs,strExtension);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218910/rename-a-file-in-c-sharp)?

Comment: @K.Gkinis Yes, but I need a useful technique to automatically set from 1 to ....

Comment: I really do not understand. Do you want to rename a file from 1 to something else? If you want to rename something to "...." you can't in Windows (and most Operating Systems)

Comment: no @K.Gkinis for example we have three folder A,B, and C. I want to move these folders to another path and change names to 1, 2, 3.

Comment: it can be acheived using simple for loop and this System.IO.File.Move("oldfilename", "newfilename");

Comment: @dahsra It doesn't very simple for me. infact I confused which part of my code would be replaced !

Answer (score 0):

If you **just** want to **rename a file after copying** it you could instead directly copy it under a different name. E.g. instead of copying `a.txt` and rename it to `b.txt` afterwards, you could just copy the original `a.txt` as `b.txt` to the destination directory.

Renaming can be done by using the [`File.Move`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
File.Move("a.txt", "b.txt");
```

---

If you want to be able to **do this even if someone else copies files** into a directory (e.g. by using the windows explorer or files written by another application), you may want to take a closer look at the [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can use it to monitor changes in a specified directory (optionally including it's subdirectories) and react on these changes.

```
...
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
watcher.Path = @"D:\SomeTestDirectory";
watcher.Filter = "*.*";
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName; // Trigger only on events associated with the filename
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;            // Starts the "watching"
...

private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
   // Do whatever you want here, e.g. rename the file.
   Console.WriteLine("File: " +  e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to modify the above code that mentioned by OP ? the code mentioned in the question is complex.