# Rename file on Network Drive using C# saying could not find part of the path

Tags: c#, io

I am trying to rename a file on a network drive and I have found this:

[Rename a file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218910/rename-a-file-in-c-sharp)

I have found numerous links about this error. Unfortunately, it hasn't fixed my issue.

This is the code that I have tried:

```
var XMLFile = @"\ServerName\DriveName\NprintDevelopment\ExternalRequestsXML\";
var XMLOldExtension = "CallNPrintReport.processed";
var XMLNewExtension = "CallNPrintReport.reques";

if (File.Exists(XMLFile + XMLOldExtension))
{
    File.Copy(XMLFile + XMLOldExtension, XMLFile + XMLNewExtension, false);
    File.Delete(XMLFile + XMLOldExtension);
}
```

I also tried:

```
var XMLFile = "\\ServerName\\DriveName\\NprintDevelopment\\ExternalRequestsXML\\";
var XMLOldExtension = "CallNPrintReport.processed";
var XMLNewExtension = "CallNPrintReport.reques";
```

What am I missing?  It is probably just something dumb but don't see the issue.

Comment: Is this a console app or a web app?

Comment: @DavidG Console App

Comment: You need a double slash at the start to specify the server e.g. `\\servername\path`. Also, `DriveName` needs to be a share name, is it a share on your server?

Comment: @DavidG, I tried that also and then I get the error 'The network name cannot be found'

Comment: Like I said, you cannot just specify `DriveName`, that folder needs to be a network share. Can you access the file by putting that string into Windows Explorer?

Comment: @DavidG, no so how do I access the D drive on a different server?  I tried looking for that and all I found was to access it by drive name.

Comment: I've said it twice now, you need to share a folder on the server, preferably not the whole drive, just the `ExternalRequestsXML` folder for example and use `\\server\ExternalRequestsXML\CallNPrintReport.processed`

Comment: thank you; I will get my IT to set up a folder share