# how to add file extensions and not delete old extensions

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, file, extension-methods

I have the desire to add file extensions and not change the old extension.
Suppose file.jpg becomes file.jpg.bmp
is that possible ?

```
string filename;
                string[] file = Directory.GetFiles(folder_path);
                foreach (string myfile in file)
                {
                    filename = Path.ChangeExtension(myfile, ".bmp");
                    System.IO.File.Move(myfile, filename);
                }
```

my code only changes extensions, for example file.jpg becomes a file .bmp

I want to be file.jpg.bmp

Please help
thanks

Comment: I guess you can rename the file, appending the `.bmp` at the end, instead of using the `Path.ChangeExtension` API. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218910/rename-a-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: BMP and JPG are very different formats. Do you *really* want to append `.bmp` to a `.jpg` file and confuse Windows Explorer and any program that tries to read that file as a BMP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
string[] file = Directory.GetFiles(folder_path);
foreach (string myfile in file)
{
      System.IO.File.Move(myfile, myfile + ".bmp");
}
```