# How to rename images in a folder after an image is deleted from them?

Tags: c#

I have 5 images in a folder. The name of the images are:
img1.jpg
img2.jpg
img3.jpg
img4.jpg
img5.jpg

If I delete img3, I want the other images below 3 to move up and  be renamed like:
img1.jpg
img2.jpg
img3.jpg
img4.jpg

I can delete specific image from the folder like this:

```
     int i = 3;
     string imgpath = @"C:\images" + "/" + "img" + i.ToString() + ".jpg";
     File.Delete(imgpath );
```

But how do I rename the images below img3 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename a file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3218910/328193)

Comment: You need to delete the file first and then rename the remaining files.

Comment: I know how to rename a file using File.Move(), but how to rename with that sequence?

Comment: @Alisha: Well, if you want to perform an operation repeatedly in a sequence, that would involve a *loop*.  What have you tried and what isn't working as expected?

Comment: is the file names enumeration always without any gaps?

Comment: @David: Thanks, Used a for loop after finding the total number of files in the directory and within the for loop, added i+1 in source file name in File.Move().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by David, I used a loop as below to fix the issue:

```
   int filecount = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length;
   int position = 3
    for (int i = position; i < filecount ; i++)
   {
     string filename1= @"C:\images" + "/" + "img" + (i + 1).ToString() + ".jpg";
     string filename2= @"C:\images" + "/" + "img" + (i).ToString() + ".jpg";
     File.Move(filename1, filename2);
   }
```