# WinUI3: How do I rename a file after picking it?

Tags: winui-3, winui

I am a novice at developing "winui" applications.I found that there is a FilePicker component in winui3. I want to use it to develop a software for batch renaming. Do you know where I can find more information about these?

I know that directly assigning a value to file.Name in the example code is useless.

Comment: In C# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218910/rename-a-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: You could try to use [StorageFile.RenameAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.renameasync?view=winrt-22621)

Comment: Did you solve your problem?